# Interpreting values produced by GLCM or texture image in ENVI?

Tags: envi

How to use values recorded in stats file ?

Also when i use texture image generated for classification..i am getting error of NaN values.

I have corrected Landsat8 image using Radiometric correction. I didn't perform DOS.

Is this due to this?

Comment: What is the precise error message that you are receiving?  And the precise steps/syntax that leads to it?

Comment: I am working in ENVI classic. Input is Landsat 8 radio-metrically corrected image. DN values converted to TOA reflectance. I didn't perform Dark Object Subtraction. I want to perform classification methods on texture image and even NDVI image but in both cases i am getting error of NAN values.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

If you convert the NAN values to zero then you will get the texture results. However, if you take mean then the zero values would affect the mean of you texture measures.